# Date comparison works locally, but not on heroku

Tags: datetime, vue.js, heroku

In a Vuejs app, I currently have a button that is usable once a day. After it is clicked once, it is disabled until the following day.  This works fine locally, but on heroku, the comparison does not seem to work.

Here is y date computed value in the vue component which returns true if the Act was created after 00:00 on the current date:

```
  computed: {
    ...
    actedToday() {
      if (!!this.$store.getters.lastAct) {
        let now = new Date();
        console.log('this is now in actedToday computed: ', now);
        let lastActDate = new Date(this.$store.getters.lastAct.created_at);
        console.log('this is last act date in computed actedToday', this.$store.getters.lastAct.created_at);
        console.log('was last Act today? ', lastActDate.getTime() > now.setHours(0,0,0,0));

        return lastActDate.getTime() > now.setHours(0,0,0,0)
      }
    }
  },
```

Here is what the console.log returns locally:

```
this is now in actedToday computed:  Fri Oct 04 2019 15:20:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
ActButton.vue?0bb7:31 this is last act date in computed actedToday 2019-10-04T19:20:23.901Z
ActButton.vue?0bb7:32 was last Act today?  true
```

And here is the analogous logs from the heroku app:

```
this is now in actedToday computed:  Fri Oct 04 2019 15:21:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
ActButton.vue:31 this is last act date in computed actedToday 2019-10-04T03:30:22.266Z
ActButton.vue:32 was last Act today?  false
```

In the first example, the comparison works as expected. In the second, although both dates are on the same day, the comparison returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs due to different timezones. Your `lastActDate` is in Zulu-time (UTC, note the `Z` at the end) but your `actedToday` is in EDT. Using `setHours(0,0,0,0)` will give you the start of the day, but in the same timezone. Thus you have the following values:

```js
//locally
now = Fri Oct 04 2019 15:20:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
now.setHours(0,0,0,0) = Fri Oct 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
lastActDate = 2019-10-04T19:20:23.901Z = Fri Oct 04 2019 15:20:23.901 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

//heroku
now = Fri Oct 04 2019 15:21:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
now.setHours(0,0,0,0) = Fri Oct 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
lastActDate = 2019-10-04T03:30:22.266Z = Fri Oct 03 2019 23:30:22.266 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Thus heroku is right and your last action has not been "today". You should consider to use the same timezone in all of your dates.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess the question is how to get the start of the day in Zulu time or conversely how to convert LastActDate to EDT, so I am comparing apples to apples, right?

Comment: I am not sure about vue.js and your project, but perhaps have a look here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-convert-utc-time-to-local-time-throughout-the-project/46540